# Gentoo kernel panic on hyper-v

Tags: linux, boot, grub, kernel, gentoo

I recently installed gentoo. I followed the guide for amd64 installation. I double-checked if the /boot was mounted before I installed the bootloader (GRUB). I chose the GPT+UEFI option for partition and boot. I have manually configured the kernel and added built-in support for (SATA, SCSi, ATA, ext4, ACHI) driver modules corresponding to the necessary drivers as well. But there is kernel panic on boot.

Here is my [grub.cfg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cp7h.png)

Here is my [/etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuR1A.png)

Here are the [drives on grub command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9qiT.png)

Here is the [kernel panic message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9zbS.png)

It is my understanding that the root partition is not identified. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually you need an initrd / initramfs that contains the driver modules that are required for `/` mounting, unless all the required drivers are built as builtin. Examples of drivers required are ahci,  sd (scsi disk), ext4 and their dependencies.

Comment: @TomYan All the driver modules are built as built-in because I have configured the kernel manually (including the ones you have specified). Since, I have configured the kernel manually I have not used an initramfs.

Comment: Evidently, you kernel is missing the required drivers to access its root filesystem. Did you enable [all the appropriate kernel options](https://www.funtoo.org/HyperV_Kernel_Configuration)?

Comment: @DanielB Thanks. I did miss out the hyper-V specific drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had not enabled Hyper-V Specific driver support (specifically the Hyper-V client driver) in the kernel.
Following the [Gentoo Hyper-V guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hyper-V) resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).